# Making My First listObjects from Amazon S3 -- Classic "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" Encountered

Tags: javascript, apache, amazon-s3, cross-domain

Here's what I've done so far.

Setup S3 with a free account, hardcoded my access keys with

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'hidden',
  secretAccessKey: 'hidden'
});

AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var myAWS = new AWS.S3();
myAWS.listObjects({Bucket: "anothertestbucketalexwait"}, function(error, data) {
  console.log("Arguments!", arguments);
});
```

Got

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://anothertestbucketalexwait.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `"http://localhost:9000"` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

when making the listObjects() call.

Read that Chrome doesn't support CORS from a localhost (using yeoman/'localhost:9000'). I setup a local dev apache server, so my hostname is s3test.local

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://anothertestbucketalexwait.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s3test.local' is therefore not allowed access.

Still not working....

I've got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

under my CORS Configuration for the the relevant bucket.

What else can I try?

Comment: Chrome has no notable issues with localhost and CORS.  Please show the request and response headers associated with this issue, according to a proxy server.

Answer (score 4):

I've just been having the same problem. Solved it by adding

`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`

to the CORS configuration for the relevant bucket

So my complete CORS configuration for direct upload to an S3 bucket is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I'm a beginner, so any comments about the security implications of doing this are more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Removing the region configuration worked for me. That is:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'hidden',
  secretAccessKey: 'hidden'
});

//AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var myAWS = new AWS.S3();
myAWS.listObjects({Bucket: "anothertestbucketalexwait"}, function(error, data) {
  console.log("Arguments!", arguments);
});
```

I figured it out by looking directly at the AWS response ...a 301 + the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
  <Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
  <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
  <Bucket>xxx</Bucket>
  <HostId>xxx</HostId>
  <Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
</Error>
```

The answer may have been a little obscure, but it was basically telling me to use s3.amazonaws.com which contains no region spec. So I commented out the region config on the AWS SDK and I was good to go.